# is there a way to resume my downloading after changing location of the download?

Tags: bittorrent

I am downloading a file using a torrent client.

When my download progress reached 80%, I changed the location of the download to F:\ folder from the location it was already downloading to - now it is restarting the download from zero.

I'm using torch browser as my torrent client. Is there a way to resume my download from where I have left?

Answer (score 0):

Your mileage may vary wildly, but essentially what you've done is downloaded part of the file to location one, and then started again by choice.

If you're lucky, the partially completed download will be in the original location you were downloading to. In this instance, you should be able to exit the torrent client, move the files from the original location to the new location (overwriting the partially completed download in the new location) and then restart the torrent client. This should then scan the partially completed download and pick up from where it left off.

If the partially completed download does not exist in the original location then you'll just have to download it all again.